# IOS Swift - How can I use 2 table views in a collectionview with different data

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app where I have a collectionview with 2 different tableviews. But what I need to know is how I can recognize which tableview is filled with data at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `UIView` Object has a `tag`property, which is [used to identify a `UIView` at runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag).

You could set it like this:

```
myTableView1.tag = Int.min
myTableView2.tag = Int.max
```

and in the `Delegate` and `DataSource` methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  let rowCount: Int
  if tableView.tag == Int.Min
  {
    rowCount = self.dataForTableView1.count
  } else 
  {
    rowCount = self.dataForTableView2.count
  }
  return rowCount
}
```

Use the `tag` value to identify the right `TableView` and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

1) Use a different delegate and data source for your 2 table views

or

2) Create outlets for your 2 tables and just compare. The delegate and data source methods pass a reference to the table

Example

```
@IBOutlet weak var table1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var table2: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.table1 {
        // something
    }
    if tableView == self.table2 {
        // something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give them different tags and then build your method around the use of these tags.

Answer (score 0):

What is a CollectionView?

```
1.It's similar to a UITableView
2.Layout grid instead of columns.
3.Defined by the UICollectionViewFlowLayout.
4.Nees a custom UICollectionViewCell
5.Requires a data source and delegate
```

It can have sections just like TableViews have multiple sections. Items in each section are equivalent to the cells in a TableView.

The UICollectionViewCells have a stack of background properties. The first thing you drag into the cell will happen on top of the cell's content view. It' a property thats like an empty tabelViewCell. There's nothing in it, it's just a view so anything you drag on top of that view will be visible. such as an ImageView, LabelView etc.

If you turn the cell.contentView background colour on it will obscure whatever is underneath it. Underneath the cell.contentView is something called the cell.backgroundView / cell.selectedBackgroundView. Those are views that are initially nil but we can populate them with our own views.

Just drag a CollectionViewController to the storyboard and mark it as the Initial Controller. Take a look in the Document Outline panel (click square at bottom of Xcode window) and you'll see the CollectionViewController comes with a collectionView and in the CollectionView is a collectionViewCell and a UICollectionViewFlowLayout which controls where the cells are.

This is where you can have all of your fun. You can place any type of Views in there. Good luck.

[image]